# Bash script reads literal as a command

Tags: bash, github, terminal

When I run this conditional in bash:

```
if [ "$(curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/MyUserName/MyRepo/releases/latest' | grep 'prerelease')" == "  "\""prerelease"\"": false" ] ; then
    let ISPRERELEASE=false
fi
```

ISPRERELEASE is still true even though it should be false. The error I get when I run just the conditional statement suggests that "prerelease": false is *command not found*.  Why does terminal think it's a command?  Also how can I fix my code so that it will set ISPRERELEASE to false when the conditions are met?

Comment: Your code isn't valid, there is a lone quote after `false`

Comment: This syntax error aside, could you provide the output of the curl, and maybe the exact source code, so that someone can help you?

Comment: GitHub's API returns json so, better to use `jq` to parse the response it will simplify things

Comment: @Nepho: No, the quotes are OK (even if most of them are unnecessary).

Comment: @choroba: They aren't OK with sh or bash. Is that really just me?

Comment: I can run the command without errors. You can simplify the RHS to `'  "prerelease": false'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a test repo on github so you can actually test things out rather than guessing at them.

## Step 1

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/safai-labs/foo/releases/latest' | grep 'prerelease'
```

Output:

> ```
>  "prerelease": false,
> ```

Notice spaces, and we only really need the `false` at the end so:

## Step 2:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/safai-labs/foo/releases/latest' | sed -n '/prerelease/{ s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\),/\1/; p }'
```

Output:

> `false`

#### Explanation of

#### `sed -n '/prerelease/{ s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\),/\1/; p }'`

> `-n` : suppresses default behavior of sed to print lines, and you explicitly have to tell sed to print something.
>
> `/prerelease/` applies the rule in *{ }* to the line that matches the regex
>
> `s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*]\),/\1/`
>
> - `s`: *sed substitute command*
> - `/` *begin matching pattern*
> - `[^:]*` *match everything that's not a `:`*
> - `[^:]*`: *match everything that's not a* `:`, *followed by a* `:`*
> - `[^:]*:[\ ]*` *match everything that's not a* `:`, *followed by a* `:` *followed by* **spaces**
> - `[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\)`: *match everything that's not a* `:` *followed by a* `:` *followed by* **spaces**, *and from here on* *capture everything that's* **not a `,`**
> - `[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\)`: *match everything that's not a* `:` *followed by a* `:` *followed by* **spaces**, *and from here on* *capture everything that's* **not a `,`**, *stop the capture*, *match next* `,`,
> - `/` end matching pattern, begin replacement string
> - `\1` - *replace everything that was matched with everything that was captured* (in this case `false`)
> - `/` - end replacement string
> - `;` - *next command*
> - `p` - print the modified line

## Step 3:

Now for our `if` statement:

```
if [ $(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/safai-labs/foo/releases/latest' | sed -n '/prerelease/{ s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\),/\1/; p }') = false ] ; then 

     echo "No prerelease found"

else

     echo "In prerelease"

fi
```

## Better Step 3

```
PRERELEASE=$(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/safai-labs/foo/releases/latest' | sed -n '/prerelease/{ s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\),/\1/; p }')
```

Comment: The better step 3 was exactly what I wanted.  Although as an fyi you need a ; after the p at the end there for it to work

Comment: You shouldn&#39;t need a ;    after the last command, but may depend on the version of sed. Glad it worked. If so,  please accept the answer.